# Making a button go to multiple screens

Tags: button, buttonclick, code.org

Let's say I have a survey composed of five questions. The final button, after completing the fifth question, is supposed to take the individual to one of many different screens, depending on their previous answers. However, despite the answers that I am inputting, it is taking me to the same screen.

Here is a section of my code:

```js
onEvent("resultbutton", "click", function(event) {

  if (getText("q1dropdown") == "Female") {

    if (getText("q2dropdown") == "0-12", "13-25", "26-39", "40 and over") {
      if (getText("q3dropdown") == "House") {
        if (getText("q4dropdown") == "Alone") {
          if (getText("q5dropdown") == "Happy", "Energetic") {
            setScreen("HAPPYGIRL");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

if (getText("q1dropdown") == "Female") {

    if (getText("q2dropdown") == "0-12", "13-25", "26-39", "40 and over") {
      if (getText("q3dropdown") == "House") {
        if (getText("q4dropdown") == "Alone") {
          if ((getText("q5dropdown") == "Tired"), "Sad") {
            setScreen("TIREDGIRL");
```

For instance, when I am inputting the answers that should be directing me to the "TIREDGIRL" screen, it will only bring me to the "HAPPYGIRL" screen.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you're trying to see if each dropdown response is any one of the comma separated values, this is actually not doing what you think.

In order to, for instance, check if `getText("q5dropdown")` is either of the values `"Tired"` or `"Sad"`, you have a couple options:

1. Use a logical [OR (||)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) operator:

   `if ( getText("q5dropdown") == "Tired" || getText("q5dropdown") == "Sad") )`
2. Check if an array of values [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) the answer:

   `if ( ["Tired", "Sad"].includes(getText("g5dropdown")) )`

The existing code is using a [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), which will return the last operand, a string, causing those conditions to always evaluate to true regardless of the selected answer.

Comment: You can also find documentation for the code.org-specific implementations of those operators and methods at https://docs.code.org/applab; see for example [the OR operator](https://docs.code.org/applab/orOperator/)